# Easy Transfer fails on XP with "you are currently logged in using a temporary profile"

Tags: windows-xp, user-profiles, windows-easy-transfer

There are multiple profiles on the XP machine I am trying to migrate from, one of which has a .BAK extension.

I launch Easy Transfer, attached the USB null modem cable when prompted, and a few minutes later I get a dialog box with "You are currently logged in using a temporary profile. Restart your computer and try again." Restarting does not help.

I want only one user profile to move, not the .BAK profile, but am reluctant to delete it for fear of user data loss.

Making a new Admin equivalent user and logging in with it did not solve the problem.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/windows-easy-transfer-will-not-work-due-to-error/ef06b946-2d4f-4fbc-90bb-021684aeed85?msgId=13114a02-1fae-424f-b5cb-2ce63e964469 mentions the problem, but does not cite a solution which will enable me to transfer the user's data to the destination Win7 machine.

Comment: Sounds like the user you are logged in as has a corrupted profile, and so you're given a temporary one on login.  Make a new Admin user, login as that user and run WET with it.

Comment: Read the answer on the link you provided.  Basically - you can't use WET to transfer a corrupted profile.  Instead, your best bet is to manually copy things you need to keep out of the corrupted profile's folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the "Start Menu" on the lower left side. Select the "Run" option toward the bottom of the pop-up screen. A "Run" box will appear.

Insert "Regedit" into the "Open" box. Click the "OK" tab. The Windows XP registry appears.

Browse the tree using the following path: HKLM (HKey_Local_machine)\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList.

Here you will be looking for keys with a .bak suffix. Check the ProfileImagePath subkey and make sure to make a backup copy of everything within that path. The path will be a location on the C: drive of the computer.

Then, after the copy completes, delete the corrupted profile and its registry entry.